# how would i change the color of an array element if it meets a condition visual basic

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim r, r1, g, g1, b, b1 As Integer
    Dim grid(0 To 9, 0 To 9) As Label

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        timer1.Enabled = False
        Randomize()

        For row = 0 To 9
            For col = 0 To 9
                grid(row, col) = New Label

                grid(row, col).Width = 50
                grid(row, col).Height = 50
                grid(row, col).Left = 55 * col + 55
                grid(row, col).Top = 55 * row + 55
                grid(row, col).BackColor = Color.White

                Me.Controls.Add(grid(row, col))

                AddHandler grid(row, col).MouseEnter, AddressOf mouse_enter
            Next
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub mouse_enter(sender As Label, e As EventArgs)

        r = Int(Rnd() * 256)
        g = Int(Rnd() * 256)
        b = Int(Rnd() * 256)

        For row = 0 To 9
            For col = 0 To 9
                sender.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b)
            Next
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Dim row As Integer
        Dim col As Integer

        For row = 0 To 9
            For col = 0 To 9
                r = Int(Rnd() * 256)
                g = Int(Rnd() * 256)
                b = Int(Rnd() * 256)

                grid(row, col).BackColor = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b)
            Next
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Label2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label2.Click
        Timer1.Enabled = True
        Timer1.Interval = 800
    End Sub
End Class
```

I want to create a 10x10 array of white boxes which change into a random rgb color once the mouse goes over them, which is working fine. However, I also want the boxes which have already been colored to change into a new rgb value with each timer1 tick. With the code above it's just changing all 100 boxes within the array with each tick, no matter if its been colored or not (by the user going over it with their mouse.) Does anyone know how I would be able to get this done?

Comment: Firstly, you need to identify what your actual problem is. This really has nothing to do with changing the colour of anything. You obviously already know how to do that. It doesn't even have anything do with arrays because you can obviously access an element. The issue is identifying whether or not you have already acted on a `Label`.

Comment: It should be obvious that, when you want to do something IF a specific condition is satisfied, you need an `If` statement. That statement needs to test for the condition you want satisfied. What is that condition? That's what you need to think about: test for the desired condition and act if it is `True`. If there is no condition that you can easily test for then create one, e.g. set the `Tag` of a `Label` to something specific when you first act on it and then you can look for that value later to determine whether it has been acted on or not.

Comment: I think that this question perfectly demonstrates the biggest issue that beginners have, i.e. they try to write code straight from an idea of the end result, rather than working out the logic first, then writing code to implement that logic. If you try to write code without knowing what it has to do, it's unlikely to do it. If this were a manual process, how would you do it? You look at each label and check whether it was the default colour or something else and, if it was something else, you'd do whatever needed doing. Why should that change because you're doing it in code?

Comment: @jmcilhinney I tried doing (I’m not home rn so I think this is what I put)
```
If grid(row,col).BackColor.Equals(Color.White) = False Then 
        For row 0 To 4
                For col 0 To 4
                        grid(row,col).BackColor = Color.FromArgb(r,g,b)
                Next
        Next
End If
```
I know I need an if statement to check the condition, I just don’t know how I would check the actual condition of each single element in the grid aray

Comment: *"I just don’t know how I would check the actual condition of each single element in the grid aray"*. Of course you do. Think about it. If you were doing it manually, what would you do? You'd only be able to check one grid item at a time, wouldn't you? You would go through the grid and process one item at a time so, again, why would this be any different? You're already doing that. You have nested `For` loops to go through the grid and access one item at a time. You're already setting the `BackColor` of that one item so why can't you check the current value of that one item first?

Answer (score 0):

"I also want the boxes which have already been colored to change into a new rgb value with each timer1 tick." Since this is happening each time the timer ticks then the `If` statement will belong in the `Timer1.Tick` event. If you want the color to remain the same once the mouse has entered a label then add the `If` in the same way to the `mouse_enter` code.

You could check if the label's `.BackColor` is still `White` but what if the randomly selected `.BackColor` in the `mouse_enter` `Sub` happens to be `White`? Do you still want to change it? Probably it would be best to use the `.Tag` property of the Label.

When the `mouse_enter` is called, set the `.Tag` property to `"Changed"`. Then in the `.Tick` event check if the .Tag property is still `Nothing`.

Although the old vb6 `Rnd` function will work, it is better to use the .net `Random` class. Create a single instance of this class at the Form level.

I moved the code getting a random color to a separate function so we didn't need to repeat the code.

```
Private grid(0 To 9, 0 To 9) As Label
Private Rand As New Random

Private Sub Form4_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Timer1.Enabled = False
    For row = 0 To 9
        For col = 0 To 9
            grid(row, col) = New Label
            grid(row, col).Width = 50
            grid(row, col).Height = 50
            grid(row, col).Left = 55 * col + 55
            grid(row, col).Top = 55 * row + 55
            grid(row, col).BackColor = Color.White
            Controls.Add(grid(row, col))
            AddHandler grid(row, col).MouseEnter, AddressOf mouse_enter
        Next
    Next
End Sub

'The signature of this method must match the signature of Label.MouseEnter
'So sender must be As Object, not As Label
Private Sub mouse_enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'Not all Objects have a .BackColor property so we must Cast to the underlying type, Label
    Dim l = DirectCast(sender, Label)
    l.BackColor = GetNewColor()
    l.Tag = "Changed"
End Sub

Private Function GetNewColor() As Color
    Dim r = Rand.Next(256)
    Dim g = Rand.Next(256)
    Dim b = Rand.Next(256)
    Dim NewColor = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b)
    Return NewColor
End Function

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    For row = 0 To 9
        For col = 0 To 9
            If grid(row, col).Tag Is Nothing Then '.Tag has never been set
                grid(row, col).BackColor = GetNewColor()
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Label2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label2.Click
    Timer1.Enabled = True
    Timer1.Interval = 800
End Sub
```